# Imshow heatmap with array of arrays - problem with final plot/image

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib, imshow

I'd like to plot imshow heatmap but the final image looks very small and disproportional.
My data represent a distance measured between atoms (cca 10 atoms of one molecule to cca 30 atoms of other molecule) - the result is **array of arrays**. I prepared similar output for illustration, however my original dataset is bigger:

```
import numpy as np
array1 = np.random.randint(20, size=30)
array2 = np.random.randint(20, size=30)
array3 = np.random.randint(20, size=30)
array4 = np.random.randint(20, size=30)
array5 = np.random.randint(20, size=30)
array6 = np.random.randint(20, size=30)
array7 = np.random.randint(20, size=30)
array8 = np.random.randint(20, size=30)
array9 = np.random.randint(20, size=30)
arrayOfArrays = np.array([array1, array2, array3, array4, array5, array6, array7, array8, array9])
```

Then I wanted to make heatmap to see distances between the atoms, so this is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(arrayOfArrays, origin='upper')

#this is here because I use this approach to define xticks and yticks in my original plot  - here I modified the code with "len(range(0,30))" but in my original plot there is number of atoms for which I measured the distances (something like n_atoms=len(dataset1))
n_1=len(range(0,30))
n_2=len(range(0,9))
tick_interval = 1
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(n_2)[::tick_interval])
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(n_1)[::tick_interval])

# colorbar
cbar = fig.colorbar(im)
```

The final image created with this particular plot looks already small but the image with my original data is even smaller and I can't see the colors inside at all.

[image: For illustration:this is how it looks with original measured data]

I'd really appreciate any suggestions where the problem is or which part of the code should be edited? I tried to edit size of picture, add "interpolation", "ascpect"...

Comment: Did you try `ax.imshow(..., aspect='auto')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like the answer from TomiOck, but I believe that JohanC is right is you have a dataset for which you have many more columns than rows. This can be fixed by adding `aspect='auto'` to the `imshow` command.

Here is my attempt:

```py
import numpy as np
nrows = 9
ncols = 30
minv = 0 # inclusive
maxv = 20 # exclusive
arrayofArrays = np.random.randint(low=minv, high=maxv, size=(nrows,ncols))
```

You can generate the random data in one `numpy` line.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(14,8)) # width and height in inches
im = ax.imshow(arrayOfArrays, origin='upper', aspect='auto', interpolation='None')

n_1 = np.arange(ncols)
n_2 = np.arange(nrows)
tick_interval = 1
ax.set_yticks(n_2[::tick_interval])
ax.set_xticks(n_1[::tick_interval])

# colourbar
cbar = fig.colorbar(im)
```

The `aspect='auto'` stretches your image such that it fill the figure.
I also recommend using `interpolation='None'` to be absolutely sure that matplotlib does not change the colours much (https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/interpolation_methods.html).
[image: outcome]

Comment: You are absolutely right, that is the better way to do this. I've edited my answer to incorperate this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there is no need to create your arrays like that. Instead, you can use list comprehension to get everything in one line:

```
arrayOfArrays = np.array([np.random.randint(20, size=30) for _ in range(9)])
```

I know that you are probably using a dataset, however, this is useful to know for creating the data randomly :3

Also there are some other redundancies in your code, you can use

```
np.arange(30)
```

Instead of using

```
n_1 = len(range(0,30))
np.arange(n_1)
```

to create a list of integers from 0 to 30

**Matplotlib figure resizing:**
You can adjust the size of the figure, everything that is plotted with

```
fig.size_in_inches(10, 10)
```

When I insert this line in your code and run it in google colab, the output is as follows:
[image: plot with size adjusting]

If you want to adjust the size of the color bar use the `shrink` argument in the `fig.colorbar`, a value of 0.3 outputs:

[image: plot adjusting figure size and color bar size]

This is all the code changed:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

arrayOfArrays = np.array([np.random.randint(20, size=30) for _ in range(9)])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(arrayOfArrays, origin='upper')

n_1=30
n_2=9
tick_interval = 1
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(n_2)[::tick_interval]) # using np.arange directly
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(n_1)[::tick_interval])

fig.set_size_inches(10, 10) # setting figure size

# colorbar
cbar = fig.colorbar(im, shrink=0.3) # shrink parameter to adjust the size of colorbar
```

Comment: Nevermind the answer from scientist is better than mine in any way.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `plt.pcolormesh()` to do a similar thing as Scientist's answer, except you don't have to worry about your aspect ratio. By default, `imshow` make the blocks square, like pixels in an image.

Code adapted from Scientist:

```
nrows = 9
ncols = 30
minv = 0 # inclusive
maxv = 20 # exclusive
arrayofArrays = np.random.randint(low=minv, high=maxv, size=(nrows,ncols))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(14,8)) # width and height in inches
im = ax.pcolormesh(arrayofArrays)

n_1 = np.arange(ncols)
n_2 = np.arange(nrows)
tick_interval = 1
ax.set_yticks(n_2[::tick_interval])
ax.set_xticks(n_1[::tick_interval])

# colourbar
cbar = fig.colorbar(im)
```